# How to tie a BottomSheet at the bottom view of the layout

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, android-constraintlayout

Through ConstraintLayout, I am using a BottomSheet to show content of a map detail. My idea is the same used in GoogleMaps, but without the image carousel at the top.

[image]

I need to find some property to tie the BottomSheet in the bottom, using only the size from its layout, not the whole window, as below:

[image]

Here is my XML from parent view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        mapbox:center_latitude="0"
        mapbox:center_longitude="0"
        mapbox:style_url="@string/style_mapbox_streets"
        mapbox:zoom="12" />

    <!--
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_backdrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/anchor_point"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/BackDropBottomSheetBehavior" />
    -->

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:anchorPoint="@dimen/anchor_point"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/bottom_sheet_peek_height"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/BottomSheetBehaviorGoogleMapsLike">

        <include
            layout="@layout/places_bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/places_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_directions"
        app:elevation="3dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_sheet"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/ScrollAwareFABBehavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the design from BottomSheet "layout/places_bottom_sheet"

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_place_icon"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/watchmen" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Bottom Sheet Title"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- line separator -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/include2"
        layout="@layout/line_separator"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2" />

    <!-- street address-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_address_icon"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_location_on_black_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_address_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Rua tal, Nº 1234"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- phone -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_phone_icon"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_phone_black_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_phone_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="(62) 983 234 544"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 8):

BottomSheet works only inside Coordinator Layout or as BottomSheetDialogFragment popup.

Because: `app:layout_behavior` is part of Coordinator Layout

It seems like at the moment there is no way of putting BottomSheet inside ConstraintsLayout, which would be awesome.
They both extend view group so maybe one day, we will see capabilities of Coordinator Layout inside ConstraintsLayout or some mix of two.

Answer (score 0):

> Set the gravity of the layout to bottom.

Comment: Why are you using constraint layout for bottom sheet layout?

Comment: Nothing special. My response would be "why not?" =P

Answer (score 0):

In places_bottom_sheet.xml, change the layout_height of the root ConstraintLayout to "match_parent".

Answer (score -1):

Add this to bottom sheet. This will work like a charm!!!

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```