# Bottom Sheet Behaviour in Constraint Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, bottom-sheet

I've got a simple application and I'm trying to add Bottom Sheet Behaviour. I want to keep Constraint Layout but I want to get Bottom Sheet Behaviour too. I don't want Coordinator Layout and Bottom Sheet Dialog.

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="btn"
        android:text="@string/btn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_shop"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`activity_shop.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/shop"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="48dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/arrow"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_keyboard_arrow_up_white_48dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What I need to change to get this thing working?

Comment: You want to make bottom sheet dialog?

Comment: go through this https://stackoverflow.com/q/43325570/12034846

Comment: @JohnJoe I don't want a dialog.

Comment: put your ConstraintLayout inside the CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For using that use Hierarchy like this for using constraint layout:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>

    // *ViewGroup containing your fixed screen*
      <Linear/Relative/Constraint Layout>

      </Linear/Relative/Constraint Layout>

    // *ViewGroup containing your bottom sheet*
      <ConstraintLayout
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="90dp"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior" >

       </Constraintlayout>

</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

to you **activity_shop.xml** root

and change it's height to be `wrap_content`